# При перемещении exe+dll вылетает ошибка C#

Tags: c#

При запуске программы на моём пк всё нормально, но если запускать на другом, то выводит следующую ошибку

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Рядом с exe файлом находится нужный dll, но программа его не видит. В чем ошибка?
Заранее благодарю

UPD: приложение написано на формах, сборка дебаг, библиотека подключена через NuGet. Нужный dll - Json, на него исключение как раз и ссылается.
В папке сборки помимо exe и dll Json'а присутствует project_name.exe.config и project_name.pdb. Если скопировать exe и dll файл в другую папку на моём пк (вне проекта), то все работает. Если же запустить exe на другом компьютере (с dll файлом рядом) вылетает вышеуказанное исключение.

UPD2: .Net Framework

Comment: Framework или Core? Release или Debug сборка? Вручную подключали библиотеку или через NuGet? Нужный dll - это какой? В папке сборки только одна библиотека или несколько? Дополните вопрос, вы можете его редактировать.

Comment: @aepot дополнил

Comment: .NET Framework или .NET Core или .NET 5?

Comment: @aepot дополнил х2

Comment: Жаль, что Framework. Там не так просто собрать все библиотеки в один файл. Проблема скорее всего не с путями, а с версиями. Поэтому остается только одно - убедитесь, что на второй машине установлен Framework как минимум той версии, которую таргетит ваше приложение, а еще лучше переустановите его. (но не факт что точно поможет)

Comment: @aepot принято, спасибо

Comment: А вы project_name.exe.config  тоже копируете ? порою это имеет значение

Comment: @PavelPopov поместил все файлы из сборки на другой пк, всё также не работает

Comment: Какая версия  .NET Framework указана в проекте ? какая версия .NET Framework установлена на компе где не работает ? что за ОС на том компе ? какой режим компиляции AnyCPU, x86, x64 ?

Comment: Сделайте публикацию своего приложения. В меню Студии: Build > Publish.

Comment: @PavelPopov в проекте указана была 4.7.2, поменял на 4, все также. На другом компе установлена также 4 версия, стоит десятка (у меня восьмерка). Режим компиляции - AnyCPU

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov помогло, спасибо

Comment: Серьёзно? Напишите ответ: что сделали на своём компе, что потом на другом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поменял версию проекта с 4.7.2 на 4, и сделал публикацию. После этого все магическим образом заработало. На другом компе ничего не делал

Comment: Все-таки рекомендую использовать версию фреймворка не ниже, чем 4.6, а то могут возникнуть проблемы с использованием разных фичей .NET. Особенно это ощутимо, если ваше приложение использует или планирует использовать сеть (HTTP). Попробуйте обновить Framework на втором компе и опубликуйтесь под 4.7.2, должно тоже заработать, потому что 4.0 - это очень древняя штука времен Windows XP.